# "sendmany" Bitcoind jsonrpc php

Tags: php, bitcoind

Following the bitcoin api documentation, I have `$bitcoind->sendmany("$key", array($address => $value), 1, "", $address)->result();` as the jsonrpc call in php

However, it returns "JSON value is not an array as expected"

I am not using the easybitcoin.php library, but am using https://github.com/denpamusic/php-bitcoinrpc as it better suits my needs

I have tinkered about, trying

```
$addrAmt = [
 "blablaaddress" => 1.5,
 "anotheraddress" => 3.25
];

$bitcoind->sendmany("accountName", json_encode($addrAmt), 1, "", $address)->result();
```

I have no idea how to proceed from here, searched through multiple questions on Stack Overflow with similar issues but no one seems to be using the same library. Despite that, I've given their solutions a shot but I've come to no avail.

Comment: I am on the same boat.  did you resolve it yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I wanted to use this to send all funds from all accounts in a wallet to one address. However, I discovered a work around for this if you are trying to achieve the same thing I wanted. 

You can simply use `sendtoaddress` to send it all, then do a for loop and move all the balances to the main one, setting them all back to 0. This solution worked perfectly for me. Hope its what you wanted.